# Перенаправление с /index.php в корень /

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Всем привет, интересует такая вещь, на страницах при нажатии на элемент Главная Страница , есть ссылка `<a href="index.php"> Главная </a>`

Возможно ли , сделать через .`htaccess` , чтобы при нажатии на эту ссылку , открывался корень сайта , тоесть `127.0.0.1/`  (без `index.php`)

И сделать это правило только для страницы index.php но не для других

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь, я советую изменить на сервере `<a href="index.php">Главная</a>` на `<a href="/">Главная</a>`, но если это не выполнимо, тогда вот.

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: спасибо помогло , вставил это в .htaccess каждой папки сайта 
/en/ 
/ru/ 

а в корень поставил 

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^.*$ /en/ [NC,R=301,L]  

и проблема решилась , благодарю

Comment: Пожалуйста. :-)